# Passing typedef with parenthesis as an argument

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, types, typedef

I have found a piece of code with strange argument which is a type:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<class T>
int function1(T count,double)
{
    cout<<"function1 is called"<<endl;
    return 1111;
}

int main()
{
    typedef int aaaa;
    function1(1,aaaa()); 
}
```

And the output of this function is

> function1 is called

I want to know what does it mean when an argument is a type? and why should I give the function aaaa() and aaaa without parenthesis gives compiler error?

```
error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
  function1(1,aaaa); 
                  ^
```

Comment: It creates a temporary object of that type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`function1(1, aaaa)` is equivalent to `function1(1, int)` - you are trying to pass a type as an argument, which is ill-formed.

In `function1(1,aaaa())` `aaaa()` creates a temporary `int` with value `0`. See for example C++14 draft N4140 [expr.type.conv]/2:

> The expression `T()`, where `T` is a *simple-type-specifier* or *typename-specifier* for a non-array complete object type or the (possibly cv-qualified) void type, creates a prvalue of the specified type, whose value is that produced by value-initializing (8.5) an object of type `T`;

Comment: What is the advantage of creating a temporary value that will never be used?

Comment: @Gordon Why will it never be used? You pass it to a function. If the question is, what is an advantage of writing `aaaa()` instead of just `0` - it may be useful in a template code where `aaaa` is a template parameter, so you don't now its type in advance.

Comment: No, My question is that, from function view, why does function needs to receive a variable that is not used. What does this function do with type double? I am guessing that it is used for function overloading.

Comment: @Gordon it's an unused argument, it doesn't have to have a name. The reason it's present may be historical - it may had been used before. Also it may be an implementation of a virtual function, or some callback.

Answer (score 3):

`T();` where `T` is any type creates a nameless temporary of type `T`. The object created would be [value initialized](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization). As applied to `aaaa`, which is a `typedef` for `int`, a temporary `int` is created and assigned the value `0`.